# How to return a queryset of friend requests in DRF ListAPIView?

Tags: python, json, rest, django-rest-framework, mutual-friendship

I am using [this django app](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/) in my django rest framework(DRF) backend api to manage bi-directional friendships between users of my android app. In one of my DRF views I want to return a queryset of all a user's unread friend requests. In the [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/#getting-data-about-friendships) docs it says that to

> List all unread friendship requests:

```
Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=request.user)
```

Here is my ListAPIView:

```
class ListUnseenFriendRequests(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.FriendRequestSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Friend.objects.unread_requests(user=self.request.user)
```

The serializer FriendRequestSerializer looks like this:

```
class FriendRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_sent')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_received')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I use the same field names in the serializer as the [FriendshipRequest](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py#L71) model in the django-friendship source code.

When I run the server and make an api request to the corresponding endpoint /friendship/list-unseen-friend-requests/, the JSON response is the following:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

I had sent 3 friend requests to this user so the number is correct however they are all null.

How do I fix this such that the friend requests are returned none null?

I have tried changing the serializer to a ModelSerializer like so:

```
class FriendRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendshipRequest
        fields = ('from_user', 'to_user', 'created')
```

The result is the following when the api endpoint is called:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
[31/Jul/2017 08:26:32] "GET /friendship/list-unseen-friend-requests/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16150
```

Comment: What happens if you change the base to be `serializers.ModelSerializer` (and apply the necessary `Meta` class as per the docs for it?)

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
[31/Jul/2017 08:26:32] "GET /friendship/list-unseen-friend-requests/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16150

Comment: can you [edit] your post to show the new attempt?

Comment: I have edited the post @JonClements

Comment: Umm... might be leading you on a wild goose chase here... You were mentioning models so was assuming the `unread_requests` would indeed return model instances, so errr. what exactly is that function returning?

Comment: https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py#L192

Comment: It says it returns "a list of unread friendship requests"